# Pandas - Improve Performance of apply method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a scenario where I need to transform the values of a particular column based on the value present in another column in the same row, and the value in another dataframe.

Example-

```
print(parent_df)
       school         location      modifed_date
0      school_1       New Delhi     2020-04-06
1      school_2       Kolkata       2020-04-06
2      school_3       Bengaluru     2020-04-06
3      school_4       Mumbai        2020-04-06
4      school_5       Chennai       2020-04-06

print(location_df)
       school          location     
0      school_10       New Delhi
1      school_20       Kolkata     
2      school_30       Bengaluru
3      school_40       Mumbai       
4      school_50       Chennai
```

As per this use case, I need to transform the school names present in `parent_df`, based on the `location` column present in the same df, and the location property present in `location_df`

To achieve this transformation, I wrote the following method.

```
def transform_school_name(row, location_df):
    name_alias = location_df[location_df['location'] == row['location']]
    if len(name_alias) > 0:
        return location_df.school.iloc[0]
    else:
        return row['school']
```

And this is how I am calling this method

```
parent_df['school'] = parent_df.apply(UtilityMethods.transform_school_name, args=(self.location_df,), axis=1)
```

The issue is that for just 46K records, I am seeing the entire tranformation happening in around 2 mins, which is too slow. How can I improve the performance of this solution?

### EDITED

Following is the actual scenario I am dealing with wherein there is a small tranformation that is needed to be done before we can replace the value in the original column. I am not sure if this can be done within `replace()` method as mentioned in one of the answers below.

```
print(parent_df)
       school         location                  modifed_date    type
0      school_1       _pre_New Delhi_post       2020-04-06      Govt
1      school_2       _pre_Kolkata_post         2020-04-06      Private
2      school_3       _pre_Bengaluru_post       2020-04-06      Private
3      school_4       _pre_Mumbai_post          2020-04-06      Govt
4      school_5       _pre_Chennai_post         2020-04-06      Private

print(location_df)
           school          location     type
    0      school_10       New Delhi    Govt
    1      school_20       Kolkata      Private
    2      school_30       Bengaluru    Private
```

Custom Method code

```
def transform_school_name(row, location_df):
location_values = row['location'].split('_')
name_alias = location_df[location_df['location'] == location_values[1]]
name_alias = name_alias[name_alias['type'] == location_df['type']]
if len(name_alias) > 0:
    return location_df.school.iloc[0]
else:
    return row['school']


def transform_school_name(row, location_df):
    name_alias = location_df[location_df['location'] == row['location']]
    if len(name_alias) > 0:
        return location_df.school.iloc[0]
    else:
        return row['school']
```

This is the actual scenario what I need to handle, so using `replace()` method won't help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map/replace`:

```
parent_df['school'] = parent_df.location.replace(location_df.set_index('location')['school'])
```

Output:

```
      school   location modifed_date
0  school_10  New Delhi   2020-04-06
1  school_20    Kolkata   2020-04-06
2  school_30  Bengaluru   2020-04-06
3  school_40     Mumbai   2020-04-06
4  school_50    Chennai   2020-04-06
```

Comment: What about the cases where the values don't exist? In that case, I need to keep the original value intact.

Comment: @jezrael that's just update only if the location exists in `location_df`, hence `replace` instead of `map`.

Comment: I think there are duplicates, like seems seelcted only one school

Comment: @MitakshGupta that's what `replace` does. Only update the existing values, leave the non-existent intact. `map` needs an extra `fillna` followed.

Comment: reopened, not match.

Comment: replace method is still taking a minute on a dataframe with just 46K rows. Is this the expected performance?

Comment: As the replace is anyways not giving the required performance, I have edited the question to add the exact details of the problem I have at hand.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this is more of a regex issue as the pattern doesn't match exactly. First extract the required pattern, create mapping of location in parent_df to location_df, map the values.

```
pat =  '.*?' + '(' + '|'.join(location_df['location']) + ')' + '.*?' 

mapping = parent_df['location'].str.extract(pat)[0].map(location_df.set_index('location')['school'])

parent_df['school'] = mapping.combine_first(parent_df['school'])
parent_df


    school      location            modifed_date    type
0   school_10   _pre_New Delhi_post 2020-04-06      Govt
1   school_20   _pre_Kolkata_post   2020-04-06      Private
2   school_30   _pre_Bengaluru_post 2020-04-06      Private
3   school_4    _pre_Mumbai_post    2020-04-06      Govt
4   school_5    _pre_Chennai_post   2020-04-06      Private
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understood the **edited** task, the following update is to be performed:

- for each row in *parent_df*,
- find a row in *location_df* with matching location (a part of
  *location* column and *type*),
- if found, overwrite *school* column in *parent_df* with *school*
  from the row just found.

To do it, proceed as follows:

**Step 1**: Generate a MultiIndex to locate school names by city and
school type:

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([parent_df.location.str
    .split('_', expand=True)[2], parent_df.type])
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
MultiIndex([('New Delhi',    'Govt'),
            (  'Kolkata', 'Private'),
            ('Bengaluru', 'Private'),
            (   'Mumbai',    'Govt'),
            (  'Chennai', 'Private')],
           names=[2, 'type'])
```

Don't worry about strange first level column name (*2*), it will disappear soon.

**Step 2**: Generate a list of "new" locations:

```
locList = location_df.set_index(['location', 'type']).school[ind].tolist()
```

The result is:

```
['school_10', 'school_20', 'school_30', nan, nan]
```

For first 3 schools something has been found, for last 2 - nothing.

**Step 3**: Perform the actual update with the above list, through "non-null"
mask:

```
parent_df.school = parent_df.school.mask(pd.notnull(locList), locList)
```

## Execution speed

Due to usage of vectorized operations and lookup by index, my code
runs sustantially faster that *apply* to each row.

Example: I replicated your *parent_df* 10,000 times and checked with
*%timeit* the execution time of your code (actually, a bit changed
version, described below) and mine.

To allow repeated execution, I changed both versions so that they set
*school_2* column, and *school* remains unchanged.

Your code was running *34.9* s, whereas my code - only *161* ms - **261**
times faster.

## Yet quicker version

If *parent_df* has a **default** index (consecutive numbers starting from *0*),
then the whole operation can be performed with a **single** instruction:

```
parent_df.school = location_df.set_index(['location', 'type']).school[
    pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [parent_df.location.str.split('_', expand=True)[2],
         parent_df.type])
    ]\
    .reset_index(drop=True)\
    .combine_first(parent_df.school)
```

Steps:

- `location_df.set_index(...)` - Set index to 2 "criterion" columns.
- `.school` - Leave only *school* column (with the above index).
- `[...]` - Retrieve from it elements indicated by the MultiIndex
  defined inside.
- `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(` - Create the MultiIndex.
- `parent_df.location.str.split('_', expand=True)[2]` - The first level
  of the MultiIndex - the "city" part from *location*.
- `parent_df.type` - The second level of the MultiIndex - *type*.
- `reset_index(...)` - Change the MultiIndex into a default index
  (now the index is just the same as in *parent_df*.
- `combine_first(...)` - Overwrite *NaN* values in the result generated
  so far with original values from *school*.
- `parent_df.school =` - Save the result back in *school* column.
  For the test purpose, to check the execution speed, you can change it
  with *parent_df['school_2']*.

According to my assessment, the execution time is by 9 % shorter than
for my original solution.

## Corrections to your code

1. Take a look at `location_values[1]]`. It retrieves *pre* segment, whereas
   actually the **next** segment (city name) should be retrieved.
2. Ther is no need to create a temporary list, based on the first condition
   and then narrow down it, filtering with the second condition.
   Both your conditions (for equality of *location* and *type*) can be
   performed in a single instruction, so that execution time is a bit
   shorter.
3. The value returned in the "positive" case should be from *name_alias*,
   not *location_df*.

So if for some reason you wanted to stay by your code, change the
respective fragment to:

```
name_alias = location_df[location_df['location'].eq(location_values[2]) &
    location_df['type'].eq(row.type)]
if len(name_alias) > 0:
    return name_alias.school.iloc[0]
else:
    return row['school']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, what you're implementing with the apply method is a kind of join operation. Pandas excels are vectorizing operations, plus its c-based implementation of join ('merge') is almost certainly faster than a python / apply based one. Therefore, I would try to use the following solution:

```
parent_df["location_short"] = parent_df.location.str.split("_", expand=True)[2]
parent_df = pd.merge(parent_df, location_df, how = "left", left_on=["location_short", "type"], 
                     right_on=["location", "type"], suffixes = ["", "_by_location"])

parent_df.loc[parent_df.school_by_location.notna(), "school"] = \
      parent_df.loc[parent_df.school_by_location.notna(), "school_by_location"]
```

As far as I could understand, it produces what you're looking for:

[image]